# AnyThing Slider JQuery plugin working in Chrome, not in Firefox, can't find error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins

The JQuery AnythingSlider doesn't splay images in a RTL (right to left) (Hebrew) website.

It works in Chrome, but not in Firefox and Safari. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To embed the AnythingSlider into an RTL site, a simple fix is to set the ".anythingSlider" div's css to "direction:ltr". You can set any content that will be slid back to "rtl". This is a quick fix.